# Crud I made in Laravel 5.8 show error 419 page expires when sending data

Tags: laravel, forms, eloquent, crud

When I test or edit CRUD from other project it works fine, but when making CRUD eloquent myself I get 419 page expired and data not even stored... did anyone see the problem with my code?
[image]
[image]ps: 3 data here just seeder/manual, I want my CRUD successfully inserted fourth data

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/sistem', 'monocontroller@index');
Route::post('/sistem/date', 'monocontroller@newdate');
```

**app\date.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class date extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'date';
    protected $fillable = ['bln','thn'];
}
```

**monocontroller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\date;

class monocontroller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $date = date::all();
        return view('face', ['date' => $date]);
    }
public function newdate()
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'bln' => 'required',
            'thn' => 'required'
        ]);
 
        date::create([
            'bln' => $request->bln,
            'thn' => $request->thn
        ]);
        return back()->with('success','You have successfully added new date.');
    }
}
```

**face.blade.php(form segment)**

```
<form action="/sistem/date" method="post">
                    <select name="bln">
                    <option value="Januari">Januari</option>
                    <option value="Februari">Februari</option>
                    <option value="Maret">Maret</option>
                    <option value="April">April</option>
                    <option value="Mei">Mei</option>
                    <option value="Juni">Juni</option>
                    <option value="Juli">Juli</option>
                    <option value="Agustus">Agustus</option>
                    <option value="September">September</option>
                    <option value="Oktober">Oktober</option>
                    <option value="November">November</option>
                    <option value="Desember">Desember</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" value="tahun" name="thn">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Masukkan Bulan Baru">
                </form>
```

Or is it one of those Laravel settings problem?

Answer (score 1):

Put CSRF field in your form:

```html
<form ...>
    @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: when using only this I got undefined variable:request

Comment: This is another question so you can select the right answer and then tell us where did you use $request in your code?

Comment: Well, apparently... I forgot write the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Write csrf token after form tag.

Token is requard for form submit.

csrf token define both way as below.

```
<form action="/sistem/date" method="post">

    @csrf 

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

</form>
```

Comment: got 'undefined variable: request' when I implemented

Comment: @TheBetweener `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` import top of controler and then  use like that
    `public function myFunction(Request $request)
    { 
       // access $request here
    }`

Comment: Oh right... I forgot to write its parameters

Comment: by the way... is timestamp really important? because error I got now is this "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `date` (`bln`, `thn`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (April, 2022, 2022-07-30 10:22:52, 2022-07-30 10:22:52))" is there a way to not include timestamp when inserting data or I just simply change the table?

Comment: @TheBetweener Set `public $timestamps = false;` in model.set then data insert without timestamp.